# Normalize data structure what is the best choice

Tags: database, entity-framework, ef-code-first, ef-core-2.0

For a project I'm working on I'm normalizing the data I got. The result is that I have several batches. For this example: ExternalBatch, InternalBatch, and WorkerBatch.

All 3 of them are coupled to a list of requests. For one of them, I will need additional information saved to the database, for example, the status and status message.

**My question is what would be the best choice?**

Create a structure with an "abstract class" Batch which has a list of items "BatchRequest". What would be the link table between Request and different batches and add the information I need in this link table even if I only need it for one type of batch.

or

Create a structure with an abstract class Batch that only has a link table with no additional information and create a separate class with a separate link table with the additional information stored in it.

Comment: Are you talking about the difference between TPH (Table per hierarchy) and TPT (Table per type)? That is having one table for your 3 entities or having a table for each entitiy?

Comment: You can model this using inheritance or not.  There's no "best choice", just what's most convenient for your code.  So you'll have to pick a path, and see how it goes.  The simplest model is to have a single Batch class with a BatchType property.  See how that works for you.